# Python socket [WinError 10057]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am getting [WinError 10057] when I am running this code. And I have no idea why it's crashing when I browse to `localhost:8081` since the same code is working on my friends machine...

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(("", 8081))
sock.listen(2)
conn, addr = sock.accept()

ans = conn.recv(1024).decode("ascii")  
sock.sendall(bytearray("HTTP/1.1 200 ok\n", "ascii"))
sock.sendall(bytearray("\n", "ascii"))
sock.sendall(bytearray("<html>\n<body><h1>Your request</h1><p>Your client sent this request</p><pre>" + ans +"</pre></body></html>", "ascii"))
sock.close()
```

Why am I getting this error? Been searching around but can't really find an answer. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which line fails?  Just show us the traceback.  The error code means "Socket is not connected."

Comment: fails at sock.sendall(bytearray("HTTP/1.1 200 ok\n", "ascii"))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
sock.sendall(bytearray("HTTP/1.1 200 ok\n", "ascii"))
```

That should be `conn`, not `sock`, and likewise on the following lines.